# Change the white balance of an image - in php or html5

Tags: php, html, image, jpeg

I have some code that actually loads an image from a local server and services it to a client.

```
header("Content-type: {$info['mime']}");
readfile($path);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($path) .'" height="100" width="100"/>';
```

That works. However, because the white balance is not optimal I want to change that. Either automatically or at least make it always a bit warmer.

Probably the best way is to do this on the server side. Do you have any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php.

Comment: @AjAX. please use English references https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php in this area of Stack. You have time to edit.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is with an image library in php.

Please take a look at the following - [Image Processing and GD in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).